# Passing variable in a URL not working

Tags: php, html, parameter-passing, urlvariables

So as usually I put in information in the url leading towards another page like this:

```
<form action="index.php?type=question">
     <input class="log-btn extra" type="submit" value="Home">
</form>
```

Usually it always works, I even copy pasted it because I've used the exact same url before and on the other page it works but doesn't on this one it just returns empty after the questionmark like this:

> index.php?

Comment: try using input type hidden

Comment: Did you try to specify a `method` in your form such as `method='post'`?

Comment: Try using GET method if there is not any sensitive information.

Comment: There is no information in it. Just a `button` but I use form because of the style I've put on the `form`

Comment: thanks @JuliePelletier this worked

Answer (score 1):

When you want to misuse a Button as a link with URL query parameters you can do it in two ways.

In your example you try to set query parameters in the `action` attribute of the `form`. That is working as long as the `method` is not `get`, because get-parameters and URL query is exactly the same thing and submitting the form will overwrite the query with the get parameters of the form elements.

```
<form action="home.php?type=question" method="post">
  <input class="log-btn extra" type="submit" value="Home">
</form>
```

You can also set `<form method="get">` and use a button:

```
<form action="home.php" method="get">
  <button type="submit" name="type" value="question">Home</button>
</form>
```